process for resubmitting a question for review
I posted a question last night and it was marked as a duplicate and closed. I edited it for clarity and voted to reopen it, and it looks like it was closed again and marked as a duplicate of the same other question.
Is there a process by which I can have a discussion with someone about this? I'm quite sure it's not a duplicate and I'm happy to rewrite or clarify the question. The comment describing the closure sounds rather final and I wasn't sure how to tell if my question is queued for consideration somewhere or simple closed permanently.

"it was closed again" No it wasn't (It never got reopened to begin with)? Your question is still in the reopen votes queue and is waiting for reviews. One reopen vote isn't enough to reopen a question, you need 3 (unless a gold badge holder or moderator votes)

FYI: click on the little clock with an arrow circling it below the upvote/downvote buttons to see the timeline of a question. And then still look very carefully because I must admit I have misread what is said there multiple times by not taking enough time to process it.

Aha that's quite useful, thanks! @Gimby your comment confirmed what I suspected so I'm happy as far as my technical question - I just think this is actually a fairly fundamental question about MySQL that's different from the other questions on SO (I spent a long time reading those and experimenting before posting!)

Good question though, I hope it gets reopened and someone actually knows a MySQL trick to do this. The best way to make people crawl out of the woodwork is to say out loud that it can't be done.

"I edited it for clarity and voted to reopen it, and it looks like it was closed again and marked as a duplicate of the same other question." It comes across that you expected to be able to decide for yourself that your edit fixed the problem and should enable the question to be reopened. If that makes sense to you, I strongly urge you to spend more time here on the Meta site to gain a proper understanding of the question closure system and its purpose, and of the site's purpose.

@KarlKnechtel that is not at all my impression of how it works. I was simply asking whether I could have a discussion with someone about their perspective, rather than simply submitting edits and waiting to see what happens each time.

Fair enough if you didn't intend that. The linked duplicate has your answer, then.
